# Some questions on Kontsevich's moduli space

Tags: moduli-spaces, fibration, minimal-model-program

**Motivation**: Work of Eisenbud, Harris, and Mumford shows that
$\mathcal M_g$ is of general type when $g≥24$. Moreover, by Logan's function $f(g)$ , $\overline {\mathcal M_{g,n}}$ is of general type for $n \geq f(g)$

What about Kontsevich's moduli space?

Let $X$ be a smooth complex projective Calabi-Yau manifold, and $\beta\in H_2(X,\mathbb Z)$ a curve class. In Kontsevich's moduli space of stable maps, $\overline {\mathcal M}_g(X;\beta)$, which is K\"ahler orbifold:

> 1. What is the canonical metric(generalized K\"ahler Einstein metric
>      cscK,...) on  $\overline {\mathcal M}_g(X;\beta)$?
> 2. Is there any Minimal Model Program for this space?
> 3. What is $X_{can}=\text{Proj}(R(X,K_X))$ where $X=\overline{ \mathcal M}_g(X;\beta)$, and $R(X,K_X)$ means canonical ring?
> 4. Is the numerical Kodaira dimension of $\overline{ \mathcal M}_g(X;\beta)$ positive
>
>    5.Now if $\pi:X\to B$ be a Kodaira fibration surface then fibers are a curve in the moduli space of genus-$g$ Riemann surface $\mathcal
>    M_g$, then one can define a map from $X$ to the moduli space of
>      genus-$g$ one-punctured Riemann surface $\mathcal M_{g,1}$
>
> Which fibration $f:X\to C$ we must choose such that moduli space of
>   fibers be Kontsevich's moduli space?

Comment: Why do you say the moduli space of stable maps to a smooth projective Calabi-Yau is an orbifold? In general it's not even equidimensional and it's highly singular.

Comment: Jim Bryan made this same point as issoroloap when you asked a similar question before.  The moduli spaces of stable maps are occasionally nice enough to hope for a good Minimal Model Program.  However, typically they are very singular.  They are often "smooth as differential graded objects".  So if there were a good extension of the Minimal Model Program to the differential graded category, maybe that would be the correct setting for this question.